# One Repo Multiple sites Deployment Workflow

Tags: git, deployment, mercurial, workflow

I have a codebase (a Git Repo - currently hosted in Beanstalk by the development company).
Upon handover, I am trying to setup an easy to manage Development and Deployment Workflow, using Github/Bitbucket.

1) Should I stick with Git or can I move to Mercurial?
2) What I am trying to achieve is to have 1 repo for the entire codebase that can deploy to all 3 domains so that any common changes is published to all domains but not sure what to do with each domain's configuration files, which are unique on their own.
- What is the repo structure that I should setup? 1 repo with different branches or repo for the config files for each domain?
- What can I use (command etc)/ to deploy the codebase changes to all multiple domain simultaneously
- What can I use to ensure the config files for each domain stays (I don't mind to make this can be part of the deployment process, ie pull in from the config repo and redeploy)

I use git and mercurial for basic stuff like pull and push, but not much further knowledge on how I can make this desired workflow work. Appreciate if someone can advise how I can achieve this please.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I stick with Git or can I move to Mercurial?

It's your choice - you can use any of these SCMs. I'll prefer Mercurial for the set of reasons

> What is the repo structure that I should setup? 1 repo with different branches or repo for the config files for each domain?

With Git you have only one (reasonable smart) choice - single repo with branches per domain (only configs differ) + mainline, from which you merge changes into other branches

With Mercurial you can use any branching strategy (separate repos, separate named branches, anonymous branches, bookmarks) *plus* MQ-style of personalisation (common code are permanent changesets, domain-specific changed in configs stored as MQ-patches /patch per domain/, applied when it needed): I went this way on supporting of set of my personal blogs with common codebase and small additional changes on top of it - less merge, less actions, less headache